# Check if a value exist in a column and change in another Pandas based on different conditions: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following information.

Let's say I have the following list.

```
my_list = [2,3,4,5]
```

My dataframe is as follows:

df

```
Col1      Score  Value
[1,3,6]    0      Hot
[7]        10     Mild
[10,11,2]  50     Cool
[5,9]      0      Cool
[2,5,6]    100    Mild
```

I would like to check if one of the value from the list my_list exist in the column Col1. If it exist, change the value in Value column to Hot in the corresponding row by checking if `Score > 0` unless keep the value in Value column as it is.

I would like to see something like below.

```
Col1      Score  Value
[1,3,6]    0      Hot
[7]        10     Mild
[10,11,2]  50     Hot
[5,9]      0      Cool
[2,5,6]    100    Hot
```

I am just looking for a simple script that can iterate and check in every row and change a value in another column the corresponding row.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `explode` Col1 to check if the values are in my_list, then `groupby`+`any` to get a Series of booleans (True if at least one item is in the list).

Then use this and a condition on Score to `mask` the Value with "Hot" if the two conditions are met:

```
match = df['Col1'].explode().isin(my_list).groupby(level=0).any()
df['Value'] = df['Value'].mask(match & df['Score'].gt(0), 'Hot')
```

output:

```
          Col1  Score Value
0    [1, 3, 6]      0   Hot
1          [7]     10  Mild
2  [10, 11, 2]     50   Hot
3       [5, 9]      0  Cool
4    [2, 5, 6]    100   Hot
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `map()` and `where()`:

```
s1 = df['col1'].map(lambda x: any([i in my_list for i in x]))
s2 = df['Score'].gt(0)
df.assign(Value = df['Value'].mask((s1 & s2),'Hot'))
```

or

```
np.where(df['col1'].explode().isin(my_list).groupby(level=0).any() & df['Score'].gt(0),'Hot',df['Value'])
```

Old Answer:

```
s1 = df['col1'].map(lambda x: any([i in my_list for i in x]))
s2 = df['Score'].eq(0)
df.assign(Value = df['Value'].where((s1 | s2),df['Value']))
```

Output:

```
           col1  Score Value
0     [1, 3, 6]      0   Hot
1           [7]     10  Mild
2  [10, 11, 12]     50   Hot
3        [5, 9]      0  Cool
4     [2, 5, 6]    100   Hot
```