# Changing the value of column based on conditions: Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following information.

Let's say I have the following list.

my_list = [2,3,4,5]

My dataframe is as follows:

df

```
Col1      Value
[2,3,6]    Hot
[7]        Mild
[10,11]    Cool
[5,9]      Cool
[2,5,6]    Mild
```

I would like to check if one of the value from the list `my_list` exist in the column Col1. If it exist, change the value in Value column to Mild in the corresponding row. But if the Value is `Hot` keep as it is.

I would like to see something like below.

```
Col1      Value
[2,3,6]    Hot
[7]        Mild
[10,11]    Cool
[5,9]      Mild
[2,5,6]    Mild
```

I am just looking for a simple script that can iterate and check in every row and change a value in another column the corresponding row.

I have tried this.

```
df["Value"] =(d["Value"].apply(lambda x: "Mild" if  len(set(x["Col1"]).intersection(my_list)) >0 
                                            and (x["Value"] != 'Hot') else x["Value"],axis=1) )
```

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is almost identical to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454669/check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-column-and-change-in-another-pandas-based-on-differe/70454713#70454713), just change one condition:

```
match = df['Col1'].explode().isin(my_list).groupby(level=0).any()
df['Value'] = df['Value'].mask(match & df['Value'].ne('Hot'), 'Mild')
```

output:

```
        Col1 Value
0  [2, 3, 6]   Hot
1        [7]  Mild
2   [10, 11]  Cool
3     [5, 9]  Mild
4  [2, 5, 6]  Mild
```

Comment: @Hiwot consider testing the approach of Shubham, it might be faster depending on the real use-case

Comment: True, I have tried it. Since I have NaN value under Col1 it throw an error ```TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable``` But when I fill NaN fill with empty value, it works. In anyway, I used your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mask` to hide rows with `Hot` value then `explode` your dataframe before check `Col1` values are in `my_list`:

```
df.loc[df.mask(df['Value'].eq('Hot')).explode('Col1').isin(my_list)
         .groupby(level=0)['Col1'].any(), 'Value'] = 'Mild'
print(df)

# Output:
        Col1 Value
0  [2, 3, 6]   Hot
1        [7]  Mild
2   [10, 11]  Cool
3     [5, 9]  Mild
4  [2, 5, 6]  Mild
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) to check if the lists are disjoint then use boolean indexing with `loc` to update the values

```
m1 = df['Value'] != 'Hot'
m2 = df['Col1'].map(set(my_list).isdisjoint)

df.loc[m1 & ~m2, 'Value'] = 'Mild'
```

---

```
        Col1 Value
0  [2, 3, 6]   Hot
1        [7]  Mild
2   [10, 11]  Cool
3     [5, 9]  Mild
4  [2, 5, 6]  Mild
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1["Value"] =(df1.apply(lambda x: "Mild" if  len(set(pd.eval(x["Col1"])).intersection(my_list)) >0
              and (x["Value"] != 'Hot') else x["Value"],axis=1) )
df1
```